# How to export %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS

Tags: raku

Assuming there is a Module that contains the `sub MAIN`'s which is supposed to improve the startup speed. Unfortunately I am unable to use the `named-anywhere` feature that way. Is my export broken or what am I supposed to do?

```
use v6.c;

unit module My::Main;
our %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS is export = ( 'named-anywhere' => True);

multi sub MAIN() is export {
    say 1;
}

multi sub MAIN('a', :$pa) is export {
    say $pa;
}
```

Comment: This feels like a combination of NYI and a bug to me.  The dynamic variable *is* exported, because visible in the importing code.  But it has lost its value.  So I think this warrants a Rakudo issue to make sure we either fix this or determine this is undefined / unwanted / illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot currently export dynamic variables that way, and maybe we never will.

In the meantime, since this is usually in the context of Command Line scripts, there is a way around this:

```
# in your module:
PROCESS::<%SUB-MAIN-OPTS><named-anywhere> = True;

# in your script
dd %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS'
# Hash element = ${:named-anywhere}
```

What you're doing there is that your setting the `named-anywhere` key in the `%SUB-MAIN-OPTS` hash that lives in the `PROCESS::` namespace.  That is the outer namespace in which dynamic variables are looked up if they cannot be found anywhere else in the stack.  Note that the assignment to the key `named-anywhere` will actually vivify the hash if it doesn't exist yet.  So this will not interfere with any other future additions to the `%SUB-MAIN-OPTS` hash.

Answer (score 4):

While you can probably export `MAIN` that way, you have to consider the scope of the [`%*SUB-MAIN-OPTS` variable](https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli#%*SUB-MAIN-OPTS). It's not clear to me if you are setting the value in the module that imports or in the exporting module. In any case, just print the value within the `MAIN` subs to check it. I would say that, as a dynamic variable, you will have to set it in the importing module.