# Accessing resources of a dynamically loaded module

Tags: module, raku

I can't find a way to correctly get access to resources of an installed distribution. For example, when a module is loaded dynamically:

`require ::($module);`

One way to get hold of its `%?RESOURCES` is to ask module to have a sub which would return this hash:

`sub resources { %?RESOURCES }`

But that adds extra to the boilerplate code.

Another way is to deep scan `$*REPO` and fetch module's distribution meta.

Are there any better options to achieve this task?

Comment: I would say this is related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53544352/how-to-export-sub-main-opts) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634257/obtaining-the-pod-of-a-module-without-explicitly-exporting-it). There seems to be a necessity to include in the symbol table some lexically scoped variables so that they can be accessed. There's [this request](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2532) in the Rakudo repo and a possible workaround (which adds boilerplate too, I'm afraid)

Comment: Looks like a request for more generic way to access precompilation data is needed. BTW, accessing pod is of special interest as it would allow something similar to p5's Pod::Weaver but without the downside of having to rewrite source code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use `$*REPO` ( as you already mention ) along with the `Distribution` object that `CompUnit::Repository` provides as an interface to the META6 data and its mapping to a given data store / file system.

```
my $spec = CompUnit::DependencySpecification.new(:short-name<Zef>);
my $dist = $*REPO.resolve($spec).distribution;
say $dist.content("resources/$_").open.slurp for $dist.meta<resources>.list;
```

Note this only works for installed distributions at the moment, but would work for not-yet-installed distributions ( like `-Ilib` ) with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/1812

Comment: Sadly, https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/1812 has bitrotted a bit.  FWIW, that discussion has completely passed me by :-(

Comment: @ugexe – thanx! Wish the CompUnit family be well documented. I tried reading the sources, found the `content` method but it's not really a self-explanatory one. ;) Anyway, looking forward for the not-yet-installed support.