# Multiple MAIN signatures

Tags: signature, raku

I have a package with multiple main and I want to define several options:

My code is something like this:

```
package Perl6::Documentable::CLI {
    proto MAIN(|) is export {*}
    my %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS = :named-everywhere;

    multi MAIN(
        "setup"
    ) { ... }

    multi MAIN (
        "start"                           ,
        Str  :$topdir              = "doc",
        Bool :v(:verbose($v))      = False
    ) { ... }
```

But when I try to actually execute it with:

```
perl6 -Ilib bin/documentable start -v --topdir=ss
```

It outputs this line:

```
Usage:
  bin/documentable [--topdir=<Str>] [-v|--verbose] start
```

I am using %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS but it looks like it does not work neither.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to export the dynamic variable `%*SUB-MAIN-OPTS`, but that is still Not Yet Implemented completely: the export works sorta, but winds up being an empty hash.  So not very useful.

Rakudo will call a subroutine called `RUN-MAIN` when it decides there is a `MAIN` sub to be run.  You *can* actually export a `RUN-MAIN` from your module, and set up the dynamic variable, and then call the original `RUN-MAIN`:

```
sub RUN-MAIN(|c) is export {
    my %*SUB-MAIN-OPTS = :named-anywhere;
    CORE::<&RUN-MAIN>(|c)
}
```

For more information about `RUN-MAIN`, see: https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli#index-entry-RUN-MAIN